# Exibir posição em tempo real no mapa

Tags: php, javascript

Como exibir a posição atual em tempo real no mapa?

achei esse código na internet onde exibe as marcações no mapa:

```
<div id="mapa" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```

.

```
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    $('.modal').modal();
  });


var markersData = [
  <?php do { ?> {
    lat: <?php echo $row_rs['lat']; ?>,
    lng: <?php echo $row_rs['lon']; ?>,
    //nome: "Parque de Campismo Praia da Barra",
    //morada1:"Rua Diogo Cão, 125",
    //morada2: "Praia da Barra",
    //codPostal: "3830-772 Gafanha da Nazaré" // não colocar virgula no último item de cada marcador
  },
  <?php } while ($row_rs = $rs->fetch_assoc()); ?>
];



var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var lat = document.getElementById("lat");
var lon = document.getElementById("lon");


function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "A geolocalização não é suportada por este navegador.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  //x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  //    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  lat.value = position.coords.latitude;
  lon.value = position.coords.longitude;

}

function showError(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "Usuário negou a solicitação de geolocalização."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "As informações de localização estão indisponíveis."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "A solicitação para obter a localização do usuário atingiu o tempo limite."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "Ocorreu um erro desconhecido."
      break;
  }
} <
/script>

<
script src = "map.js" > < /script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ativar a posição tem tempo real da pessoa, para que possa saber se esta perto de alguma marcação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @BrunoFonseca Coloquei o código no meu site e não aconteceu nada. Teria que mudar algum código?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

Comment: @adventistaam Coloquei o código no meu site e também não deu.

Comment: Você está usando a chave gerada pelo google?

Comment: @adventistaam Sim, estou, e meu site tambem tem https.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse exemplo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/dannymarkov/ubrvm4ao/)

Comment: @adventistaam Não seria aquele tipo de marcação. Seria como esse https://prnt.sc/mx1bwy o mesmo que aparece no mapa do android.

Comment: Mas ele é personalizável

Comment: @adventistaam gente do ceu! Que negócio difícil! Eu não estou conseguindo fazer essa marcação!